# Mysql point to segment distance query

Tags: mysql

Hi I want to make a query to a Mysql DB 5.1 version. There must be a distance calculation from a give point to a segment defined by two points inside the DB.
I have a point to distance algorithm very similar to this one:

[Shortest distance between a point and a line segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment)

This is JS but can work as an example:

```
function sqr(x) { return x * x }
function dist2(v, w) { return sqr(v.x - w.x) + sqr(v.y - w.y) }
function distToSegmentSquared(p, v, w) {
var l2 = dist2(v, w);
if (l2 == 0) return dist2(p, v);
var t = ((p.x - v.x) * (w.x - v.x) + (p.y - v.y) * (w.y - v.y)) / l2;
if (t < 0) return dist2(p, v);
if (t > 1) return dist2(p, w);
return dist2(p, { x: v.x + t * (w.x - v.x),
                y: v.y + t * (w.y - v.y) });
}
function distToSegment(p, v, w) { return Math.sqrt(distToSegmentSquared(p,      v, w)); }
```

And the DB query the idea is the following:

```
SELECT
id, (
//should it calculate the distance here?
)
) AS distance
FROM markers
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Should I declare a procedure?

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks

EDIT:
data structure:

```
Table markers:
id | x1 | y1 | x2 | y2            
----------------------
   |    |    |    |
```

Comment: Please add the data structure on which you want to execute your calculation to your post.

Comment: Hi, I've added the data structure. Thanks

Comment: Not an answer but maybe a point to start for you:
If you are on MySQL >= 5.6.1 check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-distance

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention it's mySQL 5.1 I think it doesn't allow this function.
Do you think I should create a procedure and then call it from the SELECT part of the query?